# Does Build with parameters plugin work with Active choices plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, I wanted to know that if I use both those plugins at the same time, does the url generated for Build With Parameters plugin include information about both the pages of Active choices plugin, for example: the url opens to a page to select between 3 options, the next page that opens already has information plugged into it from the url clicked on earlier. Also, can the first page have a pre-selected option depending on the url that's been clicked earlier.

I have not yet tried working with both the plugins at the same time, and I wanted to know the expected result or whether it was even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your ask correctly, so you want to enable Jenkins parameter which is dependent to the previous parameter, and popup it's values based on the previous parameters.
Then, definitely it's possible and works as charm.

Once you installed active choice Parameter plugin, three new parameter types become available:

- Active Choices Parameter
- Active Choices Reactive Parameter
- Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter

In most cases you have to use combination of above 3 option as per your requirements.

Please check the https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/ for further details and example of use.